# visualize raw output of SQL Lab query in superset

Tags: python, sql, visualization, apache-superset

I run a simple query in SQL Lab and get the following output

```
SELECT timestamp, nav from account_info
```

[image]

I would like to visualize this "raw" output simply as a timeseries line chart.

However, when I click the visualize button, the only options I have are to perform some aggregation (counting, summing, avging, etc.).

I do not want to aggregate, I simply want to visualize the output of the sql query. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe an aggregation is indeed typically - if not always - required.

That being said, the workaround is to do a meaningless aggregation: 
In your case, after clicking `Visualize`, check both `timestamp` and `nav` as `is_dimension`, check `timestamp` as `is_date`, and define `agg_func` as `MIN(x)` for `nav`.

Click `Visualize`, select `Visualization Type` as `Time Series - Line Chart`, set `Metrics` as `min__nav` and remove the `Group By`.

Query and you should get what I think you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you! this does seem to work.

I was able to add the column to the "metrics" selection option by adding it as a metric in the table settings. the raw column value then becomes available in the "metrics" dropdown (without needing to aggregate in some way):

This method is a bit cumbersome, though, as I would have to manually add each column I wanted to views as a new "metic"

Comment: the option is sources > tables > edit record > list metrics > click add button > name it the column name and make SQL expression column name as well, so in this case just "nav" for both"

Comment: Just so I'm clear - and potentially edit the answer: you're saying the alternative is not to use SQL Lab, instead configure the table under Sources > Table; and then under List Metrics, click the add button to explicitly configure the `nav` column as a metric. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

When working with time series related visualization you will need to set up a default DATETIME field from your database table before processing.
To add main DATETIME column in superset you simply go to

```
Sources->tables->edit table
```

then set a default DATETIME column from your table.
For this you do not need to write a SQL query. Just choose the columns you want the visualization on in the table while creating slice.You can also choose time column and grain of time.